# should I secure erase my Samsung SSDs?

Tags: ssd, secure-erase

I have two SSDs in my laptop, they're a samsung evo 500GB and a samsung evo 1TB. I've noticed that my laptop has become slower these days and I was thinking of helping my SSDs to 'rejuvenate'. I've read about the secure erase procedure and I can do it with Samsung Magician. I'm not sure if it's going to help though because I benchmarked the two drives (with Samsung Magician again) and their performance is similar: approximately 560MB/s (read) and 530MB/s (write). IOPS read=34000 write=28000. I don't believe they were much higher when I first installed the drives but I'm not sure.

So I've got two questions:  (1) do I have to do a secure erase? Has their performance degraded based on the numbers I've mentioned? and (2) since I have the OS on the first disk, I'm going to have to copy the disk to an external HDD or SSD and copy it back to the Samsung SSD after doing the secure erase. Will copying the disk also copy the unused blocks and result in a disk without - securely erased - free blocks?

Comment: Writing to every cell on the drive is going to make performance worse, not better. Investigate TRIM - see this for starters… https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/04/ask-ars-my-ssd-does-garbage-collection-so-i-dont-need-trim-right/

Comment: @Tetsujin: I've read about TRIM but I thought that TRIM is not enough and you may need secure erase from time to time. Since I'm using windows 10 most of the time and both drives support TRIM, am I OK, or should I consider secure erase?